# A combinatorics identity

Tags: finite-groups, enumerative-combinatorics

Let $G$ be a finite group, for any positive integer $n$ we have a wreath product $G\wr \Sigma_{n}$. It is well know that the conjugacy classes of $G\wr \Sigma_{n}$ is classified by sequences $\{m_{r}(c)\}_{[c]\in[G],1\leq r\leq n}$ such that $\sum\limits_{[c]\in[G],1\leq r\leq n}rm_{r}(c)=n$ where $[G]$ means the set of conjugacy classes of the finite group $G$ and $m_{r}(c)$ denotes the number of length $r$-cycles with cycle product in the conjugacy class $[c]$. Let $\chi: G\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ be a class function i.e. if $c_{1},c_{2}$ are in a same conjugacy class of $G$ then $\chi(c_1)=\chi(c_2)$. Does the following equality hold for any finite group $G$ and any positive integer $n$?
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{\sum\limits_{r,[c]}rm_{r}(c)=n}\prod_{[c]\in [G]}\chi(c)^{\sum\limits_{r}m_{r}(c)}\sharp\{m_{r}(c)\}_{[c]\in[G],1\leq r\leq n}=\big(\sum\limits_{c\in G}\chi(c)\big)\big(\sum\limits_{c\in G}\chi(c)+|G|\big)\cdots\big(\sum\limits_{c\in G}\chi(c)+n|G|-|G| \big)
\end{equation}
Where $|G|$ is the order of $G$,$\sharp\{m_{r}(c)\}_{[c]\in[G],1\leq r\leq n}$ means the number of group elements in $G\wr \Sigma_{n}$ with the same conjugacy class represented by the sequence $\{m_{r}(c)\}_{[c]\in[G],1\leq r\leq n}$ and the summation in the left hand side is actually over the conjugacy classes of $G\wr \Sigma_{n}$. I checked that this is true for $G=C_{2}$: the cyclic group of order $2$ and $n=2$. I believe it should be true in general. Also I think this is related in some sense with the exponential generating functions but I don't know to prove it.

I am very sorry about this bad notation, let me try to explain it again with a concrete example $G=C_{2}$ and $n=2$. Given a finite group $G$ and the associated wreath product $G\wr \Sigma_{n}$, then sequence $\{m_{r}(c)\}_{1\leq r\leq n, [c]\in [G]}$ classifies all conjugacy classes of $G\wr \Sigma_{n}$ where $1\leq r\leq n$ and $c$ values in all conjugacy classes of $G$. So given any group element $a\in G\wr\Sigma_{n}$ the all group elements conjugate to $a$ has a presentation: the sequence $\{m_{r}(c)\}_{1\leq r\leq n, [c]\in [G]}$. For each fixed number $r$ and a conjugacy class $[c]$, $m_{r}(c)$ means the number of numbers of $r$-cycles with cycle product lies in this conjugacy class $[c]$. Therefore all conjugacy classes corresponds to the solution of the equation $\sum\limits_{r,[c]}rm_{r}(c)=n$

Moreover, $\sharp(\{m_{r}(c)\}_{1\leq r\leq n, [c]\in [G]})$ means the number of group elements in $G\wr\Sigma_{n}$ which is conjugate to $a$, i.e. the number of group elements in $G\wr \Sigma_{n}$ which have the same presntation  $\{m_{r}(c)\}_{1\leq r\leq n, [c]\in [G]}$.

Now let $G=C_{2}$ the cyclic group of order $2$ generated by $\lambda$ i.e. $\lambda^2=e$. when $n=2$, the associated wreath product is $C_{2}\wr \Sigma_{2}$. So the corresponding equation is
\begin{equation}
2m_{2}(\lambda)+2m_{2}(e)+m_{1}(\lambda)+m_{1}(e)=2
\end{equation}
This equation has $5$ solutions:

1. $m_{2}(\lambda)=m_{1}(\lambda)=m_{1}(e)=0, m_{2}(e)= 1$ and the corresponding $\sharp\{0,1,0,0\}=2$
2. $m_{2}(\lambda)=1, m_{2}(e)=m_{1}(\lambda)=m_{1}(e)=0$ and the corresponding $\sharp\{1,0,0,0\}=2$
3. $m_{2}(\lambda)=m_{2}(e)=0,m_1(\lambda)=0,m_{1}(e)=2$ and the corresponding $\sharp\{0,0,0,2\}=1$
4. $m_{2}(\lambda)=m_{2}(e)=0,m_1(\lambda)=2,m_{1}(e)=0$ and the corresponding $\sharp\{0,0,2,0\}=1$
5. $m_{2}(\lambda)=m_{2}(e)=0, m_{1}(\lambda)=m_{1}(e)=1$ and the corresponding $\sharp\{0,0,1,1\}=2$

And in this case the left hand side of the equation I want to prove is 
\begin{equation}
2\chi(e)+2\chi(\lambda)+\chi(e)^2+\chi(\lambda)^2+2\chi(e)\chi(\lambda)
\end{equation}

And the right hand side is equal to 
\begin{equation}
(\chi(e)+\chi(\lambda))(\chi(e)+\chi(\lambda)+2)=2\chi(e)+2\chi(\lambda)+\chi(e)^2+\chi(\lambda)^2+2\chi(e)\chi(\lambda)
\end{equation}
So the equality we want to prove is true when $G=C_{2}$ and $n=2$.

Comment: Please could you explain what $\sharp \{m_r(c)\}_{[c]\in[G], 1 \le r \le n}$ means? On one reading this is the size of a set whose members are parametrised by conjugacy classes in $G$ and the numbers between $1$ and $n$, so the size is clearly $k(G)n$. But I doubt this is what you want. It might also help to write out your proposed identity in the case of $C_2$ with less notation.

Comment: @MarkWildon Hi, Thank you so much for your comments. I have edited my question with a concrete example. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like an interesting question and I'm sorry I don't have time to think about it more. Have you checked your identity in any cases when $G$ is not abelian?

Comment: @MarkWildon Hi, sorry about the previous comment. This identity should work for all finite groups and the explanation is very similar to the explanation for the Stirling Numbers of first kind for rising factorial.